# Google cloud storage doesnt add CORS header to OPTIONS call

Tags: cors, xmlhttprequest, google-cloud-storage

We are trying to get a basic file download as XHR working from google cloud storage.

Already set the cors settings for the bucket using gsutil with the json

```
[{
  "origin": ["*"],
  "method": ["*"],
  "responseHeader": ["origin"],
  "maxAgeSeconds": 1800
}]
```

And its working fine for alle methods except for OPTIONS. Unfortunatly with XHR it seems the browser is always doing an OPTIONS to check the cors headers and therefore blocks the download. I also tried to explicitly set the method in the JSON to OPTIONS, but that doesnt help.

Does anyone know why only OPTIONS is off?

Edit: for verification i am sending the request via postman.
a GET call to the asset results in a 200 OK response with the headers including

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin → *
Access-Control-Expose-Headers → origin
```

but when i send a OPTIONS call to the same asset its still a 200 OK but missing alle the Access-Controll-* headers.

Comment: Please use https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50736581/edit to edit/update the question and paste in the exact CORS error message your browser is showing you in the devtools console. Also, use devtools to check the HTTP status code of the response. Is it 200 or 204? It might instead be a 4xx or 5xx error status — in which case it won’t have the CORS response header, and indicating that the endpoints isn’t yet configured to respond correctly to OPTIONS requests.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that the attribute "method" allows a wildcard. In the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/configuring-cors#configure-cors-bucket), all the methods are explicit written:

`"method": ["GET", "HEAD", "DELETE"]`

You should try to list all the methods, OPTIONS included.

Comment: I have the same problem, even with OPTIONS explicitly listed.